# Get error Diagnostics only for the delta of a CSharpCompilation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn to perform code manipulation on C# methods. To test the validity of the rewritten code, I examine compilation errors by calling `Compilation.GetDiagnostics()`. This is done only in test stages.

This works fine, but it is too slow, specially if the rewritten methods are part of a big project that apparently is compiled again each time.

I have the compilation delta since I use `Compilation.UpdateCompilation(oldSyntaxTree, newSyntaxTree)` but it is still too slow.

Is there a way to validate only the changed parts? Such as how Visual Studio determines syntax errors while we write code?

The rewritten code is comprised of changes to a method implementation (one method at time). I don't create/remove or change anything else in the method's signature or Type.